# Where can I find docs on "(defined('mydef')) or define('mydef', 0);"

Tags: php, if-statement

It works, I'd just like to read up on it.  Everything I search for comes up 'ternery'.
I am checking if I have this defined and if not, define it.

```
// just this line:
(defined('mydef')) or define('mydef', 0);
```

it works, no 'undefined constant' errors.

```
//define('mydef', 1);
(defined('mydef')) or define('mydef', 0);
echo constant('mydef');
```

Comment: Just read the documentation of the `or` operator. It's like `||` except it has different precedence. But in this case the precedence doesn't matter. What matters is that they do short-circuiting, so the second expression is not evaluated when the first one is true.

Comment: The short-circuiting makes it like an `if` statement.

Comment: Ah, yes.  the thing to search for is short-circuit evaluation